# Слишком длинный путь или имя файла, как можно обойти

Tags: c#

Кто с большим опытом может подскажете. Пытаюсь сохранить файл с БД, он имеет слишком много символов в названии, в следствии чего вылетает ошибка `Слишком длинный путь или имя файла. Полное имя файла должно содержать меньше 260 знаков, а имя каталога - меньше 248 знаков`. Порывшись в инете наткнулся на такую библиотеку, как Delimon.Win32.I​O Library.
Но она не поддерживает FileStream, который есть у меня в коде

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
         fs.Write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
    }
```

как можно заменить FS на библиотеку Delimon, в инете инфы и примеров очень мало по такой задаче, может кто сталкивался. Либо есть какие-то другие варианты

---

попробовал сделать по примеру [этой](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10) статьи, теперь вылетает ошибка `Не удалось найти часть пути....` и собственно выводит весь путь к файлу

Comment: Это вроде как ограничение OS. Ищите как в вашей операционной системе снять подобное ограничение. А лучше, сократите название!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ типо [этого](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/blogs/jeremykuhne/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10)?

Comment: Ну вы попробуйте. Я сейчас вам лишь говорю то, что это ограничение Windows и вам лучше бы использовать имена покороче, не более. Сам я ни разу в жизни не убирал подобное ограничение и по этому дать конкретный ответ не могу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вообще конечно не желательно сокращать имя файла, попробовал сделать как в этой статье, теперь вылетает ошиба 'Не удалось найти часть пути' и собственно выводит весь путь к файлу

Comment: Наверно у вас нету например директории какой-то, которая существует в этом пути. Проверьте, что бы было создано все директории, где должен располагаться файл, либо создавайте ее через `Directory.Create(...)`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `Не удалось найти часть пути "D:\Projects\UpdateFSDB\UpdateFSDB\bin\Debug\Attn_  Mr. Yuriy , Ki R Municipality (‘City Management Platform’ - 2018, the executive training programme. Seminar ‘How to Reach Place Excellence_, March 14-15, 2018  in the Academic Lounge, Oxford, UK)_103364.TXT".` полный текст ошибки, путь правильный, диск, расположение проекта и название файла, ошибка может быть связанна с тем, что я не админ сервера с БД и может быть нету прав на сохранение\загрузку файлов?